# WTSSendMessage don't show messagebox on remote desktop

Tags: c#, c++, windows-services, topshelf

I have a Windows service application that displays a confirm popup for further action. It works fine when I install the service application on my local machine, but when I install it on the remote machine, the confirm popup is not getting displayed.

```cs
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
public static IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

public static int ConfirmPopup(string message, string title)
{
    try
    {
        WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
            WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), title, title.Length, message,
            message.Length, 3, 0, out int response, true);

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Exception:ConfirmPopup()::{ex.Message}");
        return 0;
    }
}

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WTSSendMessage(
    IntPtr hServer,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int SessionId,
    String pTitle,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int TitleLength,
    String pMessage,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int MessageLength,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Style,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Timeout,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pResponse,
    bool bWait);
```

We have to show a demo to the client on a remote machine and it's not working there. It's working fine on the local machine.

Comment: Is `WTSSendMessage()` returning false? If so, what does `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` return? Did you confirm that `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` is the correct session you actually want to display the popup on? Maybe your popup is being displayed on another active session than the one you are expecting? Use `WTSEnumerateSessions()` to see what sessions are available

Comment: Remy Lebeau, WTSSendMessage() is not returning false. There are two Traces, first is before calling WTSSendMessage() and second one is after calling. The second  trace is not getting written in the trace file. The session id is 1 and service runs in session 0.

Comment: Thanks, Remy! the popup was displaying in another session i.e. session 2.

Comment: Is there any way to get exact session Id where the message box gets displayed irrespective of whether I am on a local machine or connected remotely?

Comment: It is your responsibility to specify the correct session ID when calling `WTSSendMessage()`. `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` is not always the correct/best session to use. That is why I mentioned `WTSEnumerateSessions()`, so you can detect which sessions are present and choose one that suits your needs.

Comment: I used WTSEnumerateSessions() and found the active session Id. it worked great, Thanks, Remy!