# Why is message box not showing up over RDP

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, hyper-v, rdp

I have a simple "hello world" program with a messagebox.  It works but when I run it via Remote Desktop the MessageBox does not display (not under forms, but disappear, seems like the "messagebox.show()" script not running.)

This is a virtual hyper-v machine, running Win Server 2012.

Thecode works well in develop environment, and tried on the physical host of this hyper-v over rdp, also works as expected.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello world! from Window~");      
}
```

The MessageBox should pop up, then users should click OK button before do any other operations, such as close the window.

Is there any other setting should be checked on the virtual machine?

Comment: hi @john, thanks for your reply. but something different from the linked question. my msgbox does not pop up, not under forms. users could close the window but OK-button in the msgbox sould be pressed as expected.

Comment: Oh I see. I can't find anything for that then, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar to this other issue where they discovered the window was being displayed in a *different session*: [WTSSendMessage don't show messagebox on remote desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56528614/901156)

After locating the proper session identifier, the OP was able to get it to work, but they're doing some DLL import and using `WTSSendMessage` instead of `MessageBox` which may be out of the scope of what you intend to do.

Another possibility is to try one of the other [`MessageBox` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8#overloads) that has you specify a `IWin32Owner` to force the context inside of which the message should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your reply. i found the solution finally.
i switched "target framework" to .Net framework 4.5 under Debug-->Property-->Application which defaulted as .Net Framework 4, then compiled again. and it works.
does anyone know why msgbox not display on server2012 base on .Net framework 4 compilation?